# How to insert src dynamically from database in Bootstrap carousel by adding active class

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a Carousel in my page as below

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to=""></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to=""></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/katakali.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/kappilParavur.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/temple.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**What I Need**

I want to get the image names from database using the MySQL - php codes as below

```html
<?php
$carouselImageSql = "SELECT * FROM indexPageElements WHERE carouseImage = '1'";
$carouselImageResult = mysqli_query($conn, $carouselImageSql);
$carouselImageRow = mysqli_fetch_array($carouselImageResult);
$imageLocation = $carouselImageRow['carouseImageLocation'];
?>
```

And then insert into my html as below

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <?php
 while($carouselImageRow){
  echo '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="" ></li>';
 ?>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <?php
  echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="'.$imageLocation.'"alt="First slide">
   </div>';
 }
 ?>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**My Problem**

The issue is with the `active` class in the carousel. when I loop through using `while($carouselImageRow)` it is always adding `active` class and thus carousel not working correctly. How should I add `active` class only to the first set of data while looping and then don't add that `active` class anymore after the first set?

**Edit 1**

I rewrite the whole thing as below. But still not showing anything

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <?php
 $carouselImageSql = "SELECT * FROM indexPageElements WHERE carouseImage = '1'";
 $carouselImageResult = mysqli_query($conn, $carouselImageSql);
  
 
  
 while($carouselImageRow = mysqli_fetch_array($carouselImageResult)){
  $imageLocation = $carouselImageRow['carouseImageLocation'];
  $i = 0;
  echo '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="" ></li>';
 ?>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <?php
  if($i == 0){
   echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/'.$imageLocation.'" alt="First slide">
   </div>';
  }else{
   echo '<div class="carousel-item">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/'.$imageLocation.'" alt="First slide">
   </div>';
  }
  
  $i += 1;
 }
 ?>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Edit 2**

After gave the counter outside the while loop, it works. Please see the codes below for the working model

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <?php
 $carouselImageSql = "SELECT * FROM indexPageElements WHERE carouseImage = '1'";
 $carouselImageResult = mysqli_query($conn, $carouselImageSql);
// $carouselImageRow = mysqli_fetch_array($carouselImageResult);
  
 
   
 $i = 0;
 while($carouselImageRow = mysqli_fetch_array($carouselImageResult)){
  $imageLocation = $carouselImageRow['carouseImageLocation'];
  
  echo '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="" ></li>';
 ?>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <?php
  if($i == 0){
   echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/'.$imageLocation.'" alt="First slide">
   </div>';
  }else{
   echo '<div class="carousel-item">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/'.$imageLocation.'" alt="First slide">
   </div>';
  }
  
  $i += 1;
 }
 ?>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a counter in the while statement
I notice that you have unclosed items in the loop for the carousel indicators, so you will need to do a separate loop for that also. Also you opened the carousel-inner div inside the loop, so you would get many div's open but not closed within the loop. Hope that helps. See the counter in the carousel item loop below.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<?php
$count  = 0;
while($carouselImageRow){
    echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="'.$imageLocation.'"alt="First slide">
        </div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question by considering your suggestion to add counter. But still not working.

Comment: Those picture are stacking one on top due to active class applied for all...any idea?

Comment: Previously my code was not working due to I gave the counter inside while loop. Now I gave it outside and working correctly. Thanks buddy for giving me the right direction